# Angular ng-bind-html - prevent execution of JS code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss

I have a problem with `ng-bind-html` directive.

I get the email HTML data from external services (not trusted), so it may happen that I receive `<script>` tag inside message body. However I don't want to execute this JS code on my page. I am using `ng-bind-html` directive for this.

I created an example for this and my problem is that `alert()` function is executed. How to deny to do this?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($sce, $scope) {
    $scope.text = " <script>alert(222)</script> <script>alert(222)</script>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="text"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Suvroc/0c0ee472/8/

Comment: If you write alert then it will execute. if you dont want alert box then use console. 

    $scope.text = " <script>console.log(222)</script> <script>console.log(222)</script>";

Comment: My problem is not with just `alert` function. The source of html is not trusted so it might be anything in the script tags. My intention is to not execute this kind of code at all. I use `alert` only as an example

Answer (score 1):

Since you have referenced to an old version of AngularJS, you are prevented from getting proper errors, so it was difficult to interpret. I tried in a similar fashion and found out errors, which showed there is some problem with the text which has been bind containing `<script>`.

> Actually, when one terminates the `script` tag, like -> `</script>`, the compiler generates error, showing as invalid.

This has happened with me while I was working for a project, where, the developers *deliberately* removed the `</script>` to prevent any run-time errors. Otherwise the whole code breaks.

I don't know the actual reason behind it, but it has done the trick for us in the past.

So in my code [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/sxLqLd9z/), the script doesn't runs itself; so for your case, just removing or preventing the ending/closing of the `script` tag, might just do the trick.

Meanwhile, you can have the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  Run time binding of HTML
  <div ng-bind-html="text"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope, $sce, $timeout) {
  $scope.bindHTML = "<script>alert(123);";
  $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.bindHTML);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't stop untrusted code from running. Trivially bypassed by emails containing other XSS vectors like <img src=x onerror=alert(1)>

Comment: @Erlend, good point, however the author didn't mentioned that case in his question. Anyways, new learning are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use DOMPurify to sanitize the data before rendering it. It is the best HTML sanitizer out there. Another alternative is to escape the whole thing, but I guess there might be other HTML tags that you want to keep?

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting the `$sce` service into your controller, so it seems you are half way there. You can run the `$sce.trustAsHtml(text)` function on your text and that will sanitize it accordingly.

See the docs for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Edit: Alternatively, look into using the `$sanitize` service in tandem with `$sce`, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

`$sanitize(text);`

Comment: I already tired to do this in your way, but it doesn't help. Still the same behaviour https://jsfiddle.net/Suvroc/0c0ee472/9/

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: Have you actually tried `$sce.trustAsHtml(text)` in your angular application? and what version of Angular are you using? The JS fiddle is still rendering the JS `alert`, but I have tested that code locally with angular 1.4.8 and it works, the JS does not execute and is cleaned by the `$sce` service.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any :

```
<script src="angular-sanitize.js">
```

in your code, since sanitize is not included in the AngularJS Core.

Here is a link that explains the proper way to implement it : 
http://blog.timsommer.be/using-ngsanitize-to-render-html-strings-in-angular/

Comment: `angular-sanitize.js` is included in JS fiddle (in External Resources). Also I can repeat this regular file. I don't wan't to skip validation. I want to make sure that `<script>` tag won't execute JS code